# Can I negatively close a SFTP file transfer from the client side?

Tags: sftp, ibm-sterling

I am interacting with a SFTP server that deletes files once they are downloaded. To prevent data loss, I need to read the file, land it on persistent storage and then close the connection to indicate I have received it. What's not obvious to me is what happens if I can't safely store the file. Is there a way to close the connection in a way that semantically indicates 'I'm closing the connection and it failed'? All I am finding in the RFC is a SSH_FXP_CLOSE message, which seems to only signal successful transfer. All the other error message types appear to only be used when a server returns a response to a client, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot signal an error to the SFTP server, that's not what SFTP is intended for.

For your particular case, simply closing an SFTP connection without closing the file explicitly (not sending the `SSH_FXP_CLOSE`) could indicate to the server that something went wrong.

Though it really depends on your server implementation, what it considers an error. The documentation of the SFTP server should describe what it is that triggers the delete.

In SFTP there's nothing like a "download" operation (contrary to FTP `RETR` command). There are only trivial file operations, like opening file (for reading or writing), reading piece of a file, closing a file. So it is not as simple as "server deletes the file after it is downloaded". The rule can say for example "server deletes the file after it is closed after being previously opened for reading" or something like that.

Comment: The server is IBM's 'Sterling Integrator' EDI Product, and my understanding is that there is a 'download counter' that is decremented at each release of a handle. Based on your information, it seems like the best choice is to abandon the read and simulate a network failure. That product appears to manage resume-able downloads, so that's a scenario it is prepared to deal with.

Comment: Your answer is appreciated. I could hardly ask for a more informed opinion.

Comment: @MartinPrikyl , I have a follow-up question that I'd like to bring to your attention, as it concerns WinSCP - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676105/where-does-this-ssh-exception-originate